# How the significand and the exponent of a floating point number are represented internally?

Tags: floating-point

I got some doubts trying to understand better how a floating point number is represented internally, maybe you can help me. So, I'm studying primarily the IEEE 754 specification and it says that a floating point number should have:

```
1 bit for significand's sign
8 bits for exponent
23 bits for significand precision
(I'm taking the Single-precision format here)
```

As you can see, it says that 1 bit is exclusively reserved for the significand **sign**, so it made me think that the significand is actually represented using **sign-and-magnitude** representation, **is that correct**? (seriously, I'm having problems to find this kind of information on the internet) If the answer is yes, then **why sign-and-magnitude representation is chosen instead of two-complement**? If the answer is no, then **why 1 bit is reserved for the sign**?

With regards to the exponent, I also have some doubts about its representation. I read in book/wiki that the exponent is an unsigned number encoded with a bias. However, obviously the exponent must represent both positive and negative numbers, **so my question is: the exponent can be interpreted differently depending on the application?** For example, if I need to use my exponent as a Two-Complement number, how can I do it if it's an unsigned number?

Thank you so much! I'm a bit lost, so if you could give me a complete explanation I would be so grateful!

Comment: Needing to actually look at the internals of a floating point number is rare. You can use them just counting on well tested software to do conversions, and the hardware to do arithmetic on them. See [Exponent Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding) for a description of how the exponent is handled, with examples.

Answer (score 2):

You should generally avoid manipulating the internals of an IEEE binary floating point number directly. Your programming language and libraries will generally take care of conversions and formatted output. Most computers have hardware arithmetic for them.

I am only going to give an outline, directed to your specific questions. Wikipedia has an article, [Single-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), that covers the subject well, with diagrams and examples.

Numbers are indeed stored in sign-and-magnitude form.

For normal numbers, the most significant digit of the actual significand must be 1, so it is not stored.

The exponent is stored as the sum of the actual exponent and a bias, 127, that ensures a non-negative bit pattern. The benefit of this system is simpler comparisons between floating point numbers. The two extreme exponent bit patterns, 0 and all bits on, are treated specially.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is sign-and-magnitude representation. However, internally your processor may encode the mantissa in the 2's complement representation. For example:

   -- For subtraction, one of the mantissas must be encoded in -ve, actually the processor chooses the one having the lowest exponent value, thus a 2's complement subtraction for the mantissa section is done.

   -- For addition, and multiplication, no internal 2's complement is required, but actualy the mantissas in addition are positive 2's complement representations.
2. If you are using the std, any x86 machine. No, the exponent is always represented in that way `unsigned representation  - (2^(n-1)-1)` where `n` is the width of the exponent section. For single-precision, `n=8` therefore the bias `2^(n-1)-1=127`, you only need to do this operation and store it within a signed varialbe, e.g. `int` in c, c++.

To understand the exponent section, we take single-precision as an example:

-- 00000000, represents denormals and zeroes representations.

-- 00000001, represents the lowest possible exponent, i.e. 1 - 127 = -126

-- 00000010, represemts the next exponent = -125, and so on.

```
 .....
```

-- 11111110, represents the maximum possible exponent = 254-127=127

-- 11111111, represents overflows and NaNs.